# get values from different arrays javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using yahoo's placemaker to extract location names from text. From this I get a callback function which gives me 2 different types of arrays.

this is the code am using but I CANT ANY of the values I want.

```
  Placemaker.getPlaces(text,function(o){
  if (typeof o.match!=='undefined' && o.match.length==1){
   latitude=o.match.place.centroid.latitude, longitude=o.match.place.centroid.longitude; 
   console.log(latitude,longitude);}

  if(typeof o.match !=='undefined'&& o.match.length==2){
    latitude=o[match].place.centroid.latitude,
    longitude=o[match].place.centroid.longitude;
   console.log(latitude,longitude);
      }
```

The first array looks like this

```
({
    match: {
        place: {
            woeId: "29007292",
            type: "Town",
            name: "Jubila, West Bengal, IN",
            centroid: {
                latitude: "23.1626",
                longitude: "87.7889"
            }
        },
        reference: [{
            woeIds: "29007292",
            placeReferenceId: "2",
            placeIds: "1",
            start: "14",
            end: "20",
            isPlaintextMarker: "1",
            text: "jubila",
            type: "plaintext",
            xpath: null
        }, {
            woeIds: "29007292",
            placeReferenceId: "3",
            placeIds: "1",
            start: "82",
            end: "88",
            isPlaintextMarker: "1",
            text: "jubila",
            type: "plaintext",
            xpath: null
        }]
    }
})
```

and the other one like this

```
({
    match: [{
        place: {
            woeId: "23424950",
            type: "Country",
            name: "Spain",
            centroid: {
                latitude: "39.8949",
                longitude: "-2.98831"
            }
        },
        reference: {
            woeIds: "23424950",
            placeReferenceId: "1",
            placeIds: "1",
            start: "64",
            end: "70",
            isPlaintextMarker: "1",
            text: "Espa\xF1a",
            type: "plaintext",
            xpath: null
        }
    }, {
        place: {
            woeId: "24865675",
            type: "Continent",
            name: "Europe",
            centroid: {
                latitude: "52.9762",
                longitude: "7.85784"
            }
        },
        reference: {
            woeIds: "24865675",
            placeReferenceId: "2",
            placeIds: "2",
            start: "93",
            end: "99",
            isPlaintextMarker: "1",
            text: "Europa",
            type: "plaintext",
            xpath: null
        }
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
if (typeof o.match!=='undefined' && o.match.length==1){
```

to

```
if (typeof o.match!=='undefined'){
```

For second:

```
for(var i in o.match) {
 console.log(o.match[i].place.centroid.latitude); //wil show all lat's in loop
}
```

or if you want first lattitude only:

```
console.log(o.match[0].place.centroid.latitude); //will show only first lat
```

Comment: yes now the first one is working.. can you tell me for the second array as well since that's the trickiest?

Comment: it gives me this error: TypeError: o.match.place is undefined

Comment: see the added code, it should be o.match[0].place if you want to get single lattitude, i tested and it worked fine for me

Comment: this code is not working   if (typeof o.match=='undefined'){
   for(var i in o.match) {
 console.log(o.match[0].place.centroid.latitude);
}}

Comment: if (typeof o.match=='undefined'){ should be  if (typeof o.match!=='undefined'){ ... you misssed " ! "

Comment: if i put "!" it checks again that array with this code  for(var i in o.match) {
 console.log(o.match[i].place.centroid.latitude); //wil show all lat's in loop
}
and it gives me error